# Unable To Create Schema Extensions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We have multiple Azure accounts for our various environments. I'm able to create schema extensions on the accounts we use for preproduction and development but for our production Azure account I'm unable to create schema extension even though setups are exactly identical.

Like our other accounts I use OAuth 2.0 token of a global admin and make HTTP POST to https://graph.windows.net/ourinstance.onmicrosoft.com/applications/ourmultitenantappId/extensionProperties?api-version=1.6 with the payload:

`{
    "name": "SA",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}`

Graph API returns with HTTP 403 Forbidden with Authorization_RequestDenied error message.

I have definitely verified user account I'm using has global admin access role, I have created multiple global admin user accounts in old Azure portal and the new Azure portal, I have compared all user and multitenant app settings between the production Azure account and preproduction Azure account and have compared the manifests as well but to no avail.

I have done all these checked for at least 5 times. I'm at a loss why I keep getting Authorization_RequestDenied error message.

Anything I could have possibly missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem resolved through Microsoft Support.

Turns out OAuth token didn't have necessary permissions despite the fact I have added permissions needed in UI. I had to explicitly grant admin consent to the application using  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client-id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2F&state=12345&prompt=admin_consent`

Answer (score 0):

As far As I know, there are two kinds of `403` error.

First one is like that **Insufficient privileges to complete the operation**. For this issue, please ensure the app has `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission.

And the second one error is like **The size of the object has exceeded its limit. Please reduce the number of values and retry your request**. This error occur when if an application tries to set a value for an additional extension property on an object for which 100 extension property values have already been set. At present, there is no work around for this issue please check whether there are schema extensions which is not used and unregistered the extension.

Comment: This active directory does not have any schema extensions registered currently. For test purposes I assigned every single delegated and application permission to Microsoft Graph and Windows Azure Active Directory APIs and still getting the same error message. I have again checked the user account I'm using is global admin.

Comment: {
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
  }
}

Comment: For this error, I suggest that you decode the access_token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) to check whether there are `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission in the token.